# FreeTDS UTF-8 insert in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, symfony, doctrine, freetds

I have a linux server with mysql with symfony framework installed.
Now i'm trying to get data from sql server 2012 and all works great except when i try to insert value in mysql database.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\x80 IN P...' for column 'note_anagrafica' at row 1
```

Seems that the problem is on data conversion.

The data type of column inside mysql where i'm trying to insert the data is:

```
text
```

And the collation is:

```
utf8_unicode_ci
```

FreeTds configuration is set on UTF-8 and driver is odbc.

Someone have a solution for this problem?

EDIT:

odbc.ini

```
[server]
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = x.x.x.x
Port = 1234
Database = databasename
TDS_Version = 8
client charseg = UTF-8
server charset = CP1252
```

freetds.conf

```
[server]
     host = x.x.x.x
     port = 1234
     tds version = 8.0
     client charset = UFT-8
     text size = 20971520
     use uft-16 = true
```

doctrine config for mysql.

```
charset: utf8mb4
          default_table_options:
              charset: utf8mb4
              collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

doctrine config for external mssql database:

```
server:
          driver_class: Lsw\DoctrinePdoDblib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDODblib\Driver
          host:     "%a_database_host%"
          port:     "%a_database_port%"
          dbname:   "%a_database_name%"
          user:     "%a_database_user%"
          password: "%a_database_password%"
          charset:  utf8mb4
```

from now i'm getting error when i'm trying to insert data to mysql comes from sql server 2012 with doctrine. 
Till now i have no problem on reading execpt that if i out the result on the web the special charaters like ø comes with � symbol.
There is a conversion that i have to made before call

```
$entityManager->persist($object);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: Did you create the text column `note_anagrafica` as `CHARACTER SET utf8` or `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`?

Comment: I have set utf8mb4 on column but I think that the problem comes from freetds because if I display the result of query on browser I see the ? On these special characters

Comment: Have you tried putting `client charset = UTF-8` into your `freetds.conf`? Is the SQL Server 2012 column type `NVARCHAR` or `NTEXT` instead of `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`?

Comment: Yes I have tried to insert UTF-8 in freetds and column is text but the collation of sql server is sql_latin1_general_cp_cs_as is correct UFT-8 conversion?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the column in SQL Server must be `NTEXT` to display Unicode, regardless of collation. Have you been able to select or insert Unicode into the column in SQL Server as a TEXT column?

Comment: I can access to sql server in read only mode so I can't change anything. But I think that is really a stupid thing if I can't read exact data comes from sql server. Is possible that it's so hard to read correct data from sql server?

Comment: Maybe there is something other than freetds?? That can I use ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the charset to utf8mb4 for doctrine config and will do the trick.

Comment: I have made this change but still get the same error. I have also made change to my.cnf (mysql) and in doctrine